# Как сделать форум более активным и надо ли это делать?

Tags: обсуждение

В моем ответе на вопрос был такой текст, который потом был удален модератором:

*Все молчат. Не спорят, не дают свои ответы, не комментируют, не голосуют. Как и зачем отвечать на вопросы, если реакции никакой. Просто не форум, а заговор молчания. Почему он стал таким?*

[https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/461350/Какой-корень-в-слове-мальчик](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/461350/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA)

**Подробности такие.** Участник дал  ответ на вопрос. Он не часто отвечает, поэтому, возможно, надеялся на какую-то реакцию, **и надо было бы как-то поддержать его инициативу.** Но прошло более суток, а никто и ничего не сказал (если не считать комментария про зайца).

Я не очень люблю тему словообразования (там много субъективных решений). Поэтому я не собиралась сама отвечать, но думала, что кто-нибудь еще ответит или прокомментирует этот ответ, но нет, все дружно молчали.

Там, конечно, мое замечание было не очень у места, поэтому я просто дублирую его здесь хотя бы для того, чтобы никто не подумал ничего плохого. Я ведь говорю из лучших побуждений, мне хочется, чтобы наш форум был лучше, активнее, чтобы люди больше общались, обменивались полезными знаниями, оценивали бы ответы друг у друга.

**А как вы считаете, такое молчание –  это  нормально?** Можно ли как-то исправить ситуацию или она в порядке вещей, всё вас устраивает?

Мне кажется, что у нас вообще стало **не принято делиться знаниями,** мне лично не удается узнать почти ничего. Вот при ответе на другой вопрос я спрашиваю: **Это союзная связь, это СПП, а какой тогда вид  придаточного?** Всего-то несколько слов надо бы сказать, а кто-нибудь мне ответил?  Нет!

[https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/461359/Поэтому-может-быть-союзным-словом](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/461359/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%8E%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC)

Answer (score 2):

Тут проблема в том, что сообщество стало двигаться в сторону академичности. Если посмотреть вопросы 5-6 летней давности то, с одной стороны там гораздо больше неверных ответов, минусов и пр., но  с другой общения, дискуссий, там тоже больше.

С чем это связано? Причин несколько:

1. Меньше людей и все друг друга знали
2. Дискуссионные вопросы, где нельзя было дать однозначный ответ.
3. Меньшее влияние модераторов, позволявшего вести сравнительно длинные диалоги

Если первый пункт может и не так важен, то без второго общения не происходит. У меня стоит игнор вопросов по пунктуации, но так как ещё и модератор, скрыл их не полностью. Так вот, периодически заглядывая на главную страницу я вижу, что других вопросов там и нет. В итоге большая (ударение можно поставить в любом месте) часть вопросов представляют собой решение конкретной проблемы с обобщающей простынёй текста, которая не специалисту будет почти не понятна. А о чём тогда спорить?

Как решить? Вопросы на разную тематику, более активное использование чатов и менее оперативная реакция модераторов на флуд.

Это всё можно было бы обсудить  при выборах модераторов, но их не произошло, так как никто не захотел им быть.